# SQL get id of max bill per waiter

Tags: postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using a PostgreSQL DB and have two tables like

> **waiters** (**id**, name)
>
> **bills** (**id**, amount, *id_waiter*)

and I am looking for the id of the bill with the maximum amount per waiter.

I found the following solution

```
SELECT waiter.id AS waiter, maxamount, bills.id AS bill
FROM waiter
JOIN (
  SELECT id_waiter, max(amount) AS maxamount
  FROM bills
  GROUP BY id_waiter) AS maxis ON maxis.id_waiter = waiter.id
JOIN bills ON maxis.maxamount = bills.amount AND waiter.id =     bills.id_kellner
```

It works, but it seems a bit redundant and I wonder if there is a better way to do this. What I don't like about it is that bills is joined twice, once in the sub-query and once at the end.

Here is some sample data

Sample Data

waiters table

```
id | name
1 | john
2 | joe
```

bills table

```
id | amount | id_waiter
1 | 20 | 1
2 | 25 | 2
3 | 50 | 2
4 | 20 | 1
5 | 60 | 1
6 | 10 | 2
```

Result looks like this

```
waiter | maxamount | bill
1 | 60 | 5
2 | 50 | 3
```

Comment: Sample data would be nice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres you can use [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on(id_waiter) id_waiter, amount max_amount, id bill
from bills
order by 1, 2 desc;

 id_waiter | max_amount | bill 
-----------+------------+------
         1 |         60 |    5
         2 |         50 |    3
(2 rows)
```

In fact `join` would be necessary if you want to select waiters' names too:

```
select id_waiter, name, max_amount, bill
from (
    select distinct on(id_waiter) id_waiter, amount max_amount, id bill
    from bills
    order by 1, 2 desc
    ) sub
join waiters w on w.id = id_waiter;

 id_waiter | name | max_amount | bill 
-----------+------+------------+------
         1 | john |         60 |    5
         2 | joe  |         50 |    3
(2 rows)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29479/1)

Comment: Thx @klin, this works well. If I get it right, with `distinct on` you are selecting the first of each of the groups which are ordered by id_waiter and max_amount. I wonder about the performance. My example is an abstraction over some more complex and larger dataset. I believe sorting is a bit more expensive than finding a max value, right? If I recall it correctly, finding a max should be possible in O(n), sorting lower bound being O(n log n). Both can probably be reduced by maintaining index tree structures on the amount column. My Database background is not too deep, sorry.

Comment: You are right, on non-indexed column max() is slightly faster. On my server it is ~500 ms to ~600 ms in favor of max() for 5 millions integers. On an indexed column the difference should be too small to be noticed.